# Can I replace "unless stated otherwise" with "unless they are stated otherwise"?

Tags: word-usage, clauses

> All the photographs in this book, *unless stated otherwise*, date from the 1950s.

Can I replace "unless stated otherwise" with "unless they are stated otherwise"? Does the sentence make sense to you?

Comment: I think if it was shorten from anything, the simplest one would be, *"unless (it is) stated otherwise"*. This *"It is"* is a preparatory-*it*. I haven't consulted any references yet, though.

Comment: Idiomatic usage in the context you have provided is "unless stated otherwise".  The statement should remain as is. Moreover, your suggestion, "unless they are stated otherwise", is ungrammatical.

Comment: If you simply want more words, consider "All the photographs in this book, unless they are *labeled* otherwise, date from the 1950s."

Answer (score 3):

According to Miriam-Webster, the meaning of "to state" in this context is

> "to give (specific information, instructions, rules, etc.) in writing"

Hence, "unless stated otherwise" refers to the possibility that the writer may or may not state that the date of a certain photograph is different. (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/state)

Given the above meaning, I do not see how the statement "the photographs are being stated" makes sense or is equivalent to the short form "unless stated otherwise". A suitable longer version is (see also comment by Damkerng T.)

> unless it is stated otherwise

Comment: Thank you. What does "it" in "unless it is stated otherwise" stand for? Is it "photographs don't date from the 1950s"?

Comment: The it serves the same purpose as in "It is raining", or "It is time to go", see http://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/preparatory-subject/ . The expression "unless stated otherwise" in your example means that pictures without any further comments are from the 1950s, whereas pictures from other years will have a note/comment that gives the date.